# objItems_ItemAdd not triggered when items added to olItems: How to apply the ItemAdd event?

Tags: vba, outlook

I want to set an auto-category for the incoming email in Outlook 2010 but my code does not work.

I restarted Outlook many times.

```
Public WithEvents olItems As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
Set objItems = Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Items
End Sub

Private Sub objItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
Dim objMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim strSenderEmailAddress As String
Dim objContacts As Outlook.Items
Dim objContact As Object
Dim objFoundContact As Outlook.ContactItem
Dim strFilter As String
Dim strContactCategory As String
Dim i As Long

If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
    Set objMail = Item
    strSenderEmailAddress = objMail.SenderEmailAddress
    Set objContacts = 
 Outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderContacts).Items
    For Each objContact In objContacts
        If TypeOf objContact Is ContactItem Then
            For i = 1 To 3
                strFilter = "[Email" & i & "Address] = " & 
 strSenderEmailAddress
                Set objFoundContact = objContacts.Find(strFilter)
                'Check if the sender exists in your contacts folder
                If Not (objFoundContact Is Nothing) Then
                    strContactCategory = objFoundContact.Categories
                    'If the corresponding contact has no category
                    'Assign the "Known" category to the email
                    If strContactCategory = "" Then
                        objMail.Categories = "Known"
                        'If the contact has, directly use its category
                        Else
                            objMail.Categories = strContactCategory
                     End If
                     Exit For
                End If
            Next i

            'If the sender doesn't exist in the Contacts folder
            'Assign the "Unknown" category to the email
            If objFoundContact Is Nothing Then
                objMail.Categories = "Unknown"
            End If
        End If
    Next objContact
End If
End Sub
```

I am not good in VBA. When new email arrives my mailbox, it is not auto-categorized, no color filling in Category field in Outlook, nothing happens.

Comment: What does " does not work" mean? Your event handler does not fire? Or that it raises an exception? Or that it does not do what you want it to do?

Comment: Thanks sir. I want to mean that when new email arrives my mailbox, it is not auto-categorize, no color filling in Category field in outlook, nothing happen

Comment: So have you tried to step through your code to see what goes wrong?

Comment: `objMail.Save` just before the `End If`.

Comment: `Public WithEvents objItems As Outlook.Items` not `olItems`

Answer (score 0):

> I want to set auto-category for the incoming email in outlook 2010 but my code does not work.

First of all, you need to handle the `NewMailEx` event of the Application class which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox.

The NewMailEx event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getitemfromid) method and process the item. Use this method with caution to minimize the impact on Outlook performance. However, depending on the setup on the client computer, after a new message arrives in the Inbox, processes like spam filtering and client rules that move the new message from the Inbox to another folder can occur asynchronously.

After getting the item received you may set a category.

P.S. The `ItemAdd` event may not be fired at all if you receive more than sixteen items simultaneously. This is a known issue in the Outlook object model.

Comment: Sorry sir for late response. I don't know what you mean because I am not good in VBA sir. May you explain me a little bit more?